# I'm trying to do a function that does n+nn+nnn but it returns differently from what I expected. Can someone point out the flaw in my logic?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
number = str(input('Please input a number: '))
def add_numbers(number):
    sum = 0
    for i in range (1,4):
        number = number * i
        sum += int(number)
    
    return sum
     
print(add_numbers(number)
```

> ---

> Output for range (1,2) in the loop = 5
> Output for range(1,3) in the loop = 60
> Output for range (1,4) in the loop = 555615

---

I tried it for cases where the loop iterates only once or twice which results in 5, and 5+55 = 60, respectively. But when I run it for 3 times it returns 555615. I'm guessing that it returns the correct sum which is 615 but is then added with the string 555 (which I don't understand why this does happen.

Comment: Please [edit] and fix your indentation.

Comment: generally a bad idea to use variables named like builtins

Comment: This happens because you reassign `number` inside the loop, discarding the original value.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Good Day Sir! Sorry if indentation is off, I'm new to the platform. How can I better it sir? I used CTRL+K to render the text as code automatically.

Comment: @JohnGordon This helped a lot sir! Thanks.

Comment: @kenntnisse Thanks, appreciated. Would do so to better my code :))

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
number = str(input('Please input a number: '))

def add_numbers(number):
    number = int(number)
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1,4):
        number = number ** i
        sum += int(number)

    return sum
 
print(add_numbers(number))
```

Output:

```
Please input a number:  5
15655
```

Instead of `number * i` you need `number` to the power of `i` or `number ** i`. Also, since you are passing `add_numbers` a value from `input()`, `number` is a string and you need it to be an `int` which `number = int(number)` does.

If you want the equation to be `n + nn + nnn` instead of `n * nn * nnn` this works:

```
number = str(input('Please input a number: '))

def add_numbers(number):
    number = int(number)
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1,4):
        new = number ** i
        sum += int(new)

    return sum
 
print(add_numbers(number))
```

Output:

```
Please input a number:  5
155
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply catasaurus, though my intentions were a little different (maybe because I did not explain it well enough), your reply is understood completely.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `number` is not reset back to 5 after each loop. (As per John Gordon's comment above).

With one small change, the answer you seek can be found.

```
number = input('Please input a number: ')

def add_numbers(number):

    sum_ = 0
    for i in range (1,4):
        new = number * i
        sum_ += int(new)

    return sum_
 
print(add_numbers(number))
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, just realized this as well :))

Answer (score -2):

sum will be like that = number *1 + number *2 + number *3 ...
and u want = number + number * number + number * number * number
so u should do  that :
sum += pow(number,i)